# Self Hosted Service Reporting 413 when uploading base64 encoded string

Tags: c#

I have a self hosted Rest Service and users are reporting getting 413 errors when uploading large images. It works with smaller strings

The images are being sent as a base64 encoded string.

I have a feeling it is something to do with a default limit that I need to increase from some other threads I have read.

But I have been unable to work out what an where I need to add the configuration?

Do I need to add it to the App.config?

This is my current App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="Service.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="HttpApiService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<userSettings>
<Service.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="URL" serializeAs="String">
    <value>https://localhost:8083/</value>
  </setting>
</Service.Properties.Settings>
<HttpApiService.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="URL" serializeAs="String">
    <value>https://localhost:8083/</value>
  </setting>
</HttpApiService.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have the feeling it is something along the lines of:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
  </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

But wherever I try to add that section into my app.config I get an error.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this 413 problem in a self hosted service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the answer...

```
_config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5242880; // 5mb
_config.MaxBufferSize = 5242880; // 5mb
```

In the following:

```
namespace HttpApiService
{
public partial class HttpApiService : ServiceBase
{
    private HttpSelfHostServer _server;
    //private readonly HttpSelfHostConfiguration _config; // http
    private readonly MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration _config; // https
    public string ServiceAddress = Settings.Default.URL;

    public HttpApiService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _config = new MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration(ServiceAddress);
        _config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        // added these to solve the upload size problem
        _config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5242880; // 5mb
        _config.MaxBufferSize = 5242880; // 5mb

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("HttpApiService started.");
        _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(_config);
        _server.OpenAsync();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("HttpApiService stopped.");
        _server.CloseAsync().Wait();
        _server.Dispose();
    }

    class MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration : HttpSelfHostConfiguration
    {
        public MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration(string baseAddress) : base(baseAddress) { }
        public MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration(Uri baseAddress) : base(baseAddress) { }
        protected override BindingParameterCollection OnConfigureBinding(HttpBinding httpBinding)
        {
            httpBinding.Security.Mode = HttpBindingSecurityMode.Transport;
            //Console.WriteLine("https is on");
            return base.OnConfigureBinding(httpBinding);
        }
    }
}
```

}